# RXJS, add new key:value to nested observable

Tags: javascript, recursion, rxjs, observable

I'm new with rxjs and i can't see how can i do what i need. I need to add a pair active:true recursively.

I have this data structure coming from api as observable:

```
var data = [
  {
    name: "hom",
    subcategories: [
      { name: "reb" },
      { name: "nov" },
      { name: "otr" }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "muj",
    subcategories: [
      { name: "REB" },
      { name: "NOV" },
      { name: "OT" }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "ni",
    subcategories: [
      { name: "REB", subcategories: [
        {name: "rebanis"},
        {name: "rebawos"}] },
      { name: "NOV", subcategories: [
        {name: "novebanis"},
        {name: "novrebawos"}] },
      { name: "OT", subcategories: [
        {name: "otrebanis"},
        {name: "otrebawos"}] 
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And what i want is to add a active:true on every level that have subcategories, and i don't know how many nested subcategories could be.

This is the result that i want:

```
var data = [
  {
    active: true,
    name: "hom",
    subcategories: [
      { name: "reb" },
      { name: "nov" },
      { name: "otr" }
    ]
  },
  {
    active: true,
    name: "muj",
    subcategories: [
      { name: "REB" },
      { name: "NOV" },
      { name: "OT" }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "ni",
    active: true,
    subcategories: [
      { name: "REB", active: true, subcategories: [
        {name: "rebanis"},
        {name: "rebawos"}] },
      { name: "NOV", active: true, subcategories: [
        {name: "novebanis"},
        {name: "novrebawos"}] },
      { name: "OT", active: true, subcategories: [
        {name: "otrebanis"},
        {name: "otrebawos"}] 
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I tried something like this:

```
const req = of(data)
  .pipe(
    map(data => {
      const transformedData = Object.keys(data).map(key =>
        Object.assign(data[key], { active: true })
      );
      return transformedData;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(output => console.log(output));
```

But the result is not clear and it only affects on first level not on nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` inside recursive function:

```js
const data = [ { name: "hom", subcategories: [ { name: "reb" }, { name: "nov" }, { name: "otr" } ] }, { name: "muj", subcategories: [ { name: "REB" }, { name: "NOV" }, { name: "OT" } ] }, { name: "ni", subcategories: [ { name: "REB", subcategories: [ {name: "rebanis"}, {name: "rebawos"}] }, { name: "NOV", subcategories: [ {name: "novebanis"}, {name: "novrebawos"}] }, { name: "OT", subcategories: [ {name: "otrebanis"}, {name: "otrebawos"}] } ] } ];

const addNewProp=data=>data.map(o=>o.subcategories ? ({...o, active:true, subcategories: addNewProp(o.subcategories)}) : o);

console.log(addNewProp(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has nothing to do with rxJs and Observable, it is a problem of transformation of an Array.

I would try something like this

```
data.map(el => {
  if(el.subcategories && el.subcategories.lenght > 0) {
     const newEl = {...el};
     newEl.active = true;
     return newEl;
  }
  return {...el}
})
```

Notice that here I am using some sort of immutability and hence I create new elements within the loop. If this is not required in your case, you can simplify the code like this

```
data.map(el => {
  if(el.subcategories && el.subcategories.lenght > 0) {
     el.active = true;
  }
  return el
})
```